# Pandas A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame warning does not go away using '.apply'

Tags: python, pandas

So I am using a custom function `convert_to_decimals` and I want to apply them to a column called `'Cost'`. I've tried several way but I keep getting the same error:

```
/Users/gabrielalcivar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:723: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
```

I've tried the following:

```
curr_pos.loc[:,['Cost']]=curr_pos.loc[:,['Cost']].apply(convert_to_decimals).copy(deep=False)

curr_pos.loc[:,['Cost']]=curr_pos.loc[:,['Cost']].apply(convert_to_decimals)

curr_pos['Cost']=curr_pos['Cost'].apply(convert_to_decimals).copy()

curr_pos.loc[:,['Cost']]=curr_pos['Cost'].apply(convert_to_decimals).copy()

curr_pos.loc[:,['Cost']]=curr_pos['Cost'].apply(convert_to_decimals)

curr_pos.loc[:,['Cost']].apply(convert_to_decimals)
```

Nothing has worked.

Comment: Your issue is at some point _before_ this apply code. You've created a DataFrame that is a copy of a slice. How have you created `curr_pos`?

Comment: Thank you so much! Added '.copy()' in the creation of curr_pos and it worked! Its been a long day lol

Comment: No worries. Glad it was an easy fix =)